# What does intval() actually do?

Tags: php, floating-point, integer, precision

As shown in the code sample below the conversion of a float value of `43648` to integer with `intval()` yields `int(43647)` and not `int(43648)`.

Code:

```
$f = (float)"43.650" - 0.002;
var_dump($f);
var_dump($f*1000);
var_dump(intval($f*1000));
```

Output:

```
float(43.648)
float(43648)
int(43647)
```

Why?

Comment: To me, `var_dump($f);` outputs `43.647999999999996`, not `43.648`. What version of php are you using?

Comment: Your `precision` [floating point display precision] setting is clearly set to 5, which I would call "inadvisably low". Float display rounds, but `intval()` does not, it simply drops the fraction.

Comment: @Sammitch Precision is the default 14.

Comment: @Cid PHP 7.2.24

Comment: you start with inexact floats/"doubles", then that function truncates; from python shell: print ("%.100f\n" %(43.650)) ==> 43.6499999999999985789145284797996282577514648437500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000;  print ("%.100f\n" %(0.002)) ==> 0.0020000000000000000416333634234433702658861875534057617187500000000000000000000000000000000000000000;  print ("%.100f\n" %(43.650 - 0.002))  ==> 43.6479999999999961346475174650549888610839843750000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000